# Use Scala typeclasses directly without implicit evidence object

Tags: scala, types, typeclass, implicit

I'd like to use the functions of a typeclass directly without having to refer to the implicit evidence object.

Right now I have implemented a typeclass the recommended way (at least I think so):

```
object Main {
    import Implicits._
    import Implicits.monoidInt._

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(addTwice(1,2))
    }
}

object Implicits {
    implicit object monoidInt extends Monoid[Int] {
        def zero: Int = 0
        def append(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
    }
}

trait Monoid[A] {
    def zero: A
    def append(x: A, y: A): A
}
```

Instead of writing `addTwice` like:

```
def addTwice[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit ev: Monoid[A]): A = {
        ev.append(ev.append(x,y), y)
}
```

I'd like to write:

```
def addTwice[A: Monoid[A]](x: A, y: A): A = x.append(y).append(y)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `implicitly[Monoid[A]]` as long as `A: Monoid` ?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand that question.

Comment: Is `implicitly` sufficient?

Comment: If you mean using `implicitly[Monoid[Int]].append` instead of the evidence object then no. My goal was to make functions easier to read and understand.

Comment: And you find `implicitly[TypeClass]` less readable?

Comment: Yes, I find `implicitly[Monoid].append(implicitly[Monoid].append(x, y), y)` less readable than `x.append(y).append(y)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need so called `Ops`. It allows to add methods to objects of classes that have instance of the typeclass defined.

You define the `MonoidOps` trait that has that value and instance of typeclass and then uses those in its methods, so basically it encapsulates usage of that `ev` variable.

Then define a convertion from `A` to `MonoidOps[A]` that sets the object as well as the instance that is taken through implicit parameter.

```
trait Monoid[A] {
    def zero: A
    def append(x: A, y: A): A
}

object Implicits {
    implicit object monoidInt extends Monoid[Int] {
        def zero: Int = 0
        def append(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
    }

    trait MonoidOps[A] {
        def instance: Monoid[A]
        def self: A
        def |+|(y: A): A = instance.append(self, y)
    }

    implicit def toMonoidOps[A](target: A)(implicit M: Monoid[A]) = new MonoidOps[A] {
        val instance = M
        val self = target
    }
}

import Implicits._

def addTwice[A: Monoid](x: A, y: A): A = x |+| y |+| y

scala> println(addTwice(1,2))
5
```

`MonoidOps` and `toMonoidOps` could be replaced with implicit class like this:

```
implicit class MonoidOps[A](val self: A)(implicit M: Monoid[A]) {
    def |+|(y: A): A = M.append(self, y)
}
```

Take look at [simulacrum](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) project that can generate the boilerplate for you.

Comment: I am new to Scala, but is there a reason why simulacrum type of typeclass creation isn't integrated in the language itself?

Comment: I think this is for the same reason why all other libraries aren't integrated into language. They are just libraries, if you want to use it, you add it to build file and use it, if not you don't.

Comment: I see... I think typeclasses are a core feature of a language that would benefit from agreed upon syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think they are important but they are just one of many ways of doing things. Modularity is as good think in general, you can just take what you need. For example scala swing or scala async were moved to separate projects that you have to add yourself when you want to use them.

Comment: Is it possible to have `Monoid` extend `Semigroup` and all that with `Monoid` instances which don't have to reimplement the `append` function from `Semigroup` instances?

Comment: I think things should just work if you have `Semigroup`, `SemigroupOps` with `|+|` and `Monoid extends Semigroup` and `MonoidOps` wouldn't need to contain `|+|` but you still can use `|+|` on monoids. In case it doesn't maybe post another question on this.

Comment: It doesn't work because an instance `Monoid[Int]` needs both `append` and `zero` implemented. Unless you can somehow inherit the implementation from the `Semigroup[Int]` instance.

Comment: You are right. I checked scalaz sources and they for example never defined `Semigroup` for `Int`, they just implemented instance for `Monoid[Int]` giving both `zero` and `append`. When you need just a semigroup, that instance for monoid will still work. So my suggestion is, implement monoid for monoid instances and don't implement semigroup for them, but implement semigroup when something is not a monoid.